# Comparing models fitting multivariate data

Tags: python, statistics, bayesian, pymc, pymc3

I have trouble using WAIC (widely applicable information criterion) in PyMC3. Namely, I have data which I know to be distributed according to multivariate Dirichlet distribution. I try to fit the data by assuming that marginal distributions are in one case the beta distributions, while in the other lognormal distributions. Obviously in the first case I get lower (better) WAIC value, than in the second case.

The problem arises in the third case then I assume that data is distributed according to Dirichlet distribution. The third WAIC is significantly larger (worse) than in the first two cases. I would expect this WAIC to be lower (better) than the one I get in the second (log-normal) case.

Basically I want to show that log-normal fit is bad. This is easily seen by the naked eye, but I would like to have formal result to show.

The minimal code to replicate what I get:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm

# generate the data
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.dirichlet([10,10,10],size=2000))

# fit the first case (assuming beta marginal distributions)
betaModel=pm.Model()
with betaModel:
    alpha=pm.Uniform("alpha",lower=0,upper=20,shape=3)
    beta=pm.Uniform("beta",lower=0,upper=40,shape=3)
    observed=pm.Beta("obs",alpha=alpha,beta=beta,observed=df.values,shape=df.shape)
    betaTrace=pm.sample()

# fit the second case (assuming log-normal marginal distributions)
lognormalModel=pm.Model()
with lognormalModel:
    mu=pm.Normal("mu",mu=0,sd=3,shape=3)
    sd=pm.HalfNormal("sd",sd=3,shape=3)
    observed=pm.Lognormal("obs",mu=mu,sd=sd,observed=df.values,shape=df.shape)
    lognormalTrace=pm.sample()

# fit the third case (assuming Dirichlet multivariate distribution)
dirichletModel=pm.Model()
with dirichletModel:
    alpha=pm.HalfNormal("alpha",sd=3,shape=3)
    observed=pm.Dirichlet("obs",a=alpha,observed=df.values,shape=df.shape)
    dirichletTrace=pm.sample()

# compare WAIC
print(pm.waic(betaTrace,betaModel))
print(pm.waic(lognormalTrace,lognormalModel))
print(pm.waic(dirichletTrace,dirichletModel))
```

The output is:

```
WAIC_r(WAIC=-12801.95319823564, WAIC_se=105.07502476563575, p_WAIC=5.941977774190434)
WAIC_r(WAIC=-12534.643059697866, WAIC_se=115.43257184238044, p_WAIC=6.68850211472046)
WAIC_r(WAIC=-9156.050975326929, WAIC_se=81.45146980652675, p_WAIC=2.7977039523187996)
```

I guess the problem might be related to an error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6000,) (2000,)
```

which I get when I try to run:

```
pm.compare((betaTrace,lognormalTrace,dirichletTrace),(betaModel,lognormalModel,dirichletModel))
```

Any suggestions how to obtain a reasonable comparison?

**Edit**

After thinking about the problem I would believe that it is somewhat "improper". I tend to think so because WAIC is a relative measure, thus it is likely that only similar statistical models can be reasonably compared. If the models are too dissimilar, then you get what I got.

The error I get from `pm.compare` seems to be related to how random vectors are treated. In the first two cases each component of a random vector is treated as a separate random variate (3 components per 2000 vectors = 6000 points). In the third case random vector as whole is treated as a random variate (2000 vectors = 2000 points).

Initially I thought that this problem could be resolved by reducing the number of points in the first two cases. But as the first two statistical models (wrongly) assume that components are independent, adding log-probabilities does not change anything. WAIC values remain the same.

Currently I think that a small cheat is possible. Namely to fit data to the Dirichlet distribution, but calculate WAIC as if I would have fitted the beta distribution. This gives an expected result - WAIC for the Dirichlet fit is slightly larger than WAIC for the beta fit, but smaller than WAIC for the log-normal fit.

The code for this "cheat":

```
from collections import namedtuple
from scipy.special import logsumexp

def cheat_logp(tracePoint,model):
    values=model.obs.eval()
    _,components=values.shape
    cb=[None]*components
    beta=np.sum(tracePoint["alpha"])
    for i in range(components):
        cheatBeta=pm.Beta.dist(alpha=tracePoint["alpha"][i],beta=beta-tracePoint["alpha"][i])
        cb[i]=cheatBeta.logp(values[:,i]).eval()
    return np.array(cb).T

def _log_post_trace(trace, model):
    # copy the contents of _log_post_trace function from pymc3/stats.py
    # but replace "var.logp_elemwise(pt)" with "cheat_logp(pt,model)"
    # <...>

def mywaic(trace, model=None, pointwise=False):
    # copy the contents of waic function from pymc3/stats.py
    # <...>
```

Obviously this cheat is not very "nice" and **I am still very much interested on how to achieve similar results**, but in a proper manner. Of course if it is possible.